# How to write data in "file versions" instead of writing in a single file in python?

Tags: python, io, file-writing

I am reading sensor data and saving in file like this:

```
with open('serial_data.txt','a') as f:
```

Problem is, if I write the code five times, it appends in the same file. I want the data of each test in separate file for example if I run code four times, then it should save as: *"serial_data_1.txt"*, *"serial_data_2.txt"*, *"serial_data_3.txt"*, *"serial_data_4.txt"*..... Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using CLI parameters

```
import sys

run = sys.argv[1]
with open('serial_data_{}.txt'.format(run), 'a') as f:
```

Then do `python app.py 1` for the first run

[How to read/process command line arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009860/how-to-read-process-command-line-arguments)

Otherwise, you need to save the number externally, or write a loop in your code that is processing each of your test conditions

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to write à loop in your code as:

```
for x in range(1, numberOfTest):
    with open("serial_data_{0}.txt".format(x),'a') as f
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create new files with your data in it you must use the *'w+'* tag in your open function as so:

```
    # Looping and creating multiple files
    for i in range(1, 4):
        # Using 'w+' to create file with such name if
        # it doesn't actually exit
        f = open('serial_data_{}.txt'.format(i), 'w+')
        # Now you can write any data to your file
        f.write('{} squared is {}'.format(i, i*i))
        # Close your file
        f.close()
```

This will produce 3 files with the following content:

- serial_data_1 = *"1 squared is 1"*
- serial_data_2 = *"2 squared is 4"*
- serial_data_3 = *"3 squared is 9"*

**Note: You must close the files after writing.
Additionally using 'w+' will overwrite the files every time you run it, use 'a' instead of 'w+' if you want to add/append to the file's current data.**

Hopefully that helped :)