# Python script open a json file with arguments

Tags: python

I am new on python. I am using a python script where I load a json file to set certain values to the script, but my idea is to import that file more dynamically using arguments (I think is the correct use), so I don´t need to always include the name of the json file in the python script, here is may code example:

```
import json
from pprint import pprint

with open("VariableSettings.json") as json_data:
    data = json.load(json_data)
```

so my idea is to change the code: "with open("VariableSettings.json") as json_data" with args to open the json file dynamically.

I think that on command prompt I can use the command py test.py arg1 (this represent the file path).

So I know that probably my explanation is a bit confusing but if some can help I appreciate it.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `sys` to do that. In the example below I created a file `test.json` with the content

```
{"foo": "bar"}
```

And modified your code as

```
import json
import sys

with open(sys.argv[1]) as json_data:
    data = json.load(json_data)
    print(data)
```

You need to call execute as

```
python test.py test.json
```

and the output will be

```
{'foo': 'bar'}
```

More details can be found in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009860/how-to-read-process-command-line-arguments) other post

Answer (score 5):

You can also use [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html):

```
import json
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-f", "--filename", required=True, type=str)
args = parser.parse_args()

with open(args.filename) as json_data:
    data = json.load(json_data)
    print(data)
```

Which can be called with the alias:

```
python test.py -f test.json
```

Or full argument name:

```
python test.py --filename test.json
```

And if you don't supply a file, you get:

```
usage: test.py [-h] -f FILENAME
test.py: error: the following arguments are required: -f/--filename
```

since I passed `required=True`. You can remove this if you want the argument to be optional.

Addtionally, you could also extend your program to check that if the JSON file has correct format by catching [`json.JSONDecodeError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.JSONDecodeError) with `try`/`except`:

```
with open(args.filename) as json_data:
    try:        
        data = json.load(json_data)
        print(data)
    except json.JSONDecodeError:
        print('Invalid JSON format')
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `sys` module

**Ex:**

```
import sys
import json
from pprint import pprint

if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    print("Input File Missing")
    sys.exit()

with open(sys.argv[1]) as json_data:
    data = json.load(json_data)
print(data)
```

**To Run Use**

```
python yourScriptName.py full_path_to.json
```