# Can you run a bash command calling a python file with variables?

Tags: python, bash

I'm looking to run a bash command that runs a python file ie: `"python /Users/declanmcgranahan/airflow/dags/tasks/aircall_calls_to_csv.py"`. But I have a variable in that python file that I want to define in the bash command. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean something like `python test.py var1 var2`?

Take a look at this link: [Python - Command Line Arguments](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_command_line_arguments.htm)

This even provides options function like `python test.py -a var1 -b var2`

Comment: exactly what I needed. Got it up and running. Thanks.

Comment: @declac : If you really think about having a **variable** defined in the bash world and read from Python, you could use an environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass arguments to the bash command and then read in those arguments into required variables in the `__main__` handler function. Look up [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) library on how to use it to handle provided arguments. The code in your python file should have a block:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
     # use argparse to assign variables
```

Answer (score 0):

you could pass a parameter to the python script on the command line, or you could set an environment variable in the script and have the script read it using `getenv`.

Command-line arguments: [How to read/process command line arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009860/how-to-read-process-command-line-arguments)

getenv: https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.getenv