# Python CLI program that can take args or piped input

Tags: python, shell, command-line-interface

I'm trying to create a Python program that can take in any arbitrary arguments or be passed arguments via a Posix pipe.

For example:

`program.py any arbitrary args here`

--or--

`ls -Fl | program.py`

I've been playing around with:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('args', nargs=argparse.REMAINDER)
parser.add_argument('stdin', nargs='?', type=argparse.FileType('r'), default=sys.stdin)
args = parser.parse_args().args

if not sys.stdin.isatty():
# what am I doing?
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read/process command line arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009860/how-to-read-process-command-line-arguments)

Comment: I think piped input is come from `sys.stdin`. Are they passed as arguments?