# How to pass arguments from command line to a main function in python

Tags: python, command-line-arguments

I've been doing some exercises for AI course and I to get arguments to my code directly from the command line, for example `python solution.py resolution_examples/small_example.txt`. I now in java you can pass arguments to main fun via command line, but can you do the same thing in python?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read/process command line arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009860/how-to-read-process-command-line-arguments)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sys` module has attribute argv which contains all command line parameters.

```py
import sys
print(sys.argv)
```

For fast handling, that should be enough but when you need a bit more control over cli parsing, standard library has lib called `argparse`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
import sys

print(sys.argv)
```