# Can you make shell variable assignments with Python subprocess?

Tags: python, subprocess

I have this piece of bash script code I need executed via Python

`asdf=$(function --varname var)`

What would be the best way to go about it?

I have used subprocess.run for basic function calls, but have no idea how to parse the line for variable assignments

Comment: Are you trying to have python take command line arguments [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009860/how-to-read-process-command-line-arguments)?

Comment: You can execute it, but the variable will exist in the subshell, not in Python and certainly not the shell from which you run Python.