# command line arguments options

Tags: python, windows

python myprgm.py "pathofsome" "a.py"

python myprgm.py  -file "pathofsome"  "*.c"

These are command line arguments that I will be giving in my program.How to do this?
I have to execute as a single program.How can I do this in commandline argument in python?

Comment: `import sys` then call `sys.argv` which is a list containing all the commands that were thrown to open the python interpreter. However, what is the purpose of calling two .py files in the same command-line? There might be another way to solve that problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read/process command line arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009860/how-to-read-process-command-line-arguments)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `argparse` module to handle command line arguments. `argparse` is built in python module.

Here is the official argparse
[documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html)