# How do i create custom tags for taking the input string in command line and store them in a variable in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, command, command-line-interface

The format for taking the input is:

```
myprogram.py -f "string1" -t "string2" -i "string 3 some directory path"
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read/process command line arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009860/how-to-read-process-command-line-arguments)

Comment: Hello, welcome to stackoverflow, please include the code of your program

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use the `argparse` Python module to parse the CLI parameters. I have written an example for you.

Official documentation of `argparse`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html

**Code:**

```
from argparse import ArgumentParser

parser = ArgumentParser(description=__doc__)

parser.add_argument(
    "-f",
    dest="first_string",
    help="Your first string parameter",
    required=True,
)

parser.add_argument(
    "-t",
    dest="second_string",
    help="Your second string parameter",
    required=True,
)

parser.add_argument(
    "-i",
    dest="third_string",
    help="Your third string parameter",
    required=True,
)

input_parameters, unknown_input_parameters = parser.parse_known_args()

# Set CLI argument variables.
first_arg = input_parameters.first_string
second_arg = input_parameters.second_string
third_arg = input_parameters.third_string

print("-f: {}\n"
      "-t: {}\n"
      "-i: {}".format(first_arg, second_arg, third_arg))
```

**Some output:**

```
>>> python3 test.py -f "string1" -t "string2" -i "string 3 some directory path"
-f: string1
-t: string2
-i: string 3 some directory path

>>> python3 test.py -t "string1" -f "string2" -i "string 3 some directory path"
-f: string2
-t: string1
-i: string 3 some directory path

>>> python3 test.py -t "string1" -f "string2" -i "string 3 some directory path" -x "Unused"
-f: string2
-t: string1
-i: string 3 some directory path

>>> python3 test.py -t "string1" -i "string 3 some directory path"
usage: test.py [-h] -f FIRST_STRING -t SECOND_STRING -i THIRD_STRING
test.py: error: the following arguments are required: -f

>>> python3 test.py -h
usage: test.py [-h] -f FIRST_STRING -t SECOND_STRING -i THIRD_STRING

optional arguments:
  -h, --help        show this help message and exit
  -f FIRST_STRING   Your first string parameter
  -t SECOND_STRING  Your second string parameter
  -i THIRD_STRING   Your third string parameter
```

Comment: You are welcome! If my answer solves your question, please accept my answer! :)