# how to add names to arguments when executing script Python

Tags: python-3.x, parameter-passing

I have a script which and I want to enter arguments for an sql request in my function (parameters) as following:

```
def doQuery( conn ) :
    cur = conn.cursor()
    day_start = sys.argv[1]
    day_end = sys.argv[3]
    dep_air = sys.argv[4]
    arr_air = sys.argv[5]
    aircraft = sys.argv[6]
    balname = sys.argv[7]

cur.execute( "SELECT id, day, ftfm_pp->>'name' AS Name, ftfm_pp->>'lat' AS LAT, ftfm_pp->>'lon' AS LON FROM public.pln where day between %s and %s and dep_airport = %s and arr_airport like %s and type_acft = %s and ftfm_pp->'name'?%s" , (day_start, day_end, dep_air, arr_air,aircraft,balname))

sql_data = pd.DataFrame(cur.fetchall(), columns=['ID', 'DAY', 'NAME', 'LAT', 'LON'])
.....
.....
.....
```

I want to know how to add names for my arguments like :

```
python -dayStart arg1 -dayEnd arg2 -depAir arg3 -arrAir arg4 -aircraft -arg5 -balname -arg6
```

Merci pour votre aide par avance

Comment: Argparse, perhaps? https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read/process command line arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009860/how-to-read-process-command-line-arguments)

Comment: thank's for your help