# New Screen to read instructions

Tags: python

I have a homework to do about a simple game. I have already the game, but one of the requirements is that the program must have the possibility that someone should be able to type "--help" to be taken to a screen where they can read instructions and also the user should be able to type "--resume" to go back to the game and pick up where they left off.

I have no idea how to solve it. I have been looking for the way I must solve that requirement, but can't find it.

If someone could give me a hint about the way I must go walk to fill the requirement.

Thanks

Comment: for first one, use argument, for second one, see if your program able to save the state of game and then you can start

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read/process command line arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009860/how-to-read-process-command-line-arguments)