# How to run a python script from the command prompt using date as parameter which is in the python script?

Tags: python, command-prompt, argv

I have .py file having following lines of code

```
import pandas
import sys
cwd = os.chdir("n:/user/factory")
random_date = '2019-08-20'
# dataframe created
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['salary_date'] = random_date
```

I want to run this .py file through windows command prompt and control the 'random_date' from command prompt as date parameter. For example, if I want to change the above mentioned date to '2017-01-20', it should be changeable from the command prompt and run the code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read/process command line arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009860/how-to-read-process-command-line-arguments)

Comment: Thanks for reply. Not exactly. Please suggest more.

Comment: What is unclear to you after reading the answers to the other question? There isn't more to suggest.

Comment: @mkrieger To be fair, none of the answers really say how to *get* the supplied arguments. I've submitted a small edit for the accepted answer; hopefully it'll get accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import argparse
def get_arguments():

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("--date", help="Start Date in YYY-MM-DD format", required=False, default=None)
    
    return parser.parse_args()

args = get_arguments()

random_date = args.date 

# execute script normally but add "--date 2019-08-20" at the end
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So this script needs to run in command prompt?

Comment: If you are using PyCharm you can add them as parameters under run configuration to execute from IDE. Not sure about others. Another option is to have a conditional statements like if args.date: random_date = args.date else: random_date = "whatever date you want to test with"