# pass password to a Python script on prompt

Tags: python, ansible, ansible-vault

How can I pass a password to my python script when it prompts for a password. I do not want the user to enter the password when it prompts. It should be passed directly from the script.

```py
subprocess.run(['ansible-vault', 'decrypt', 'main.yml', 'linux.yml','--ask-vault-pass'])
```

While running the script it prompts for the password. I want the password to be passed from script only not by the user or passing a password file.

Is there a way to pass the password here? I have other ansible vault option like vault-password etc but that doesn't serve my purpose.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read/process command line arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009860/how-to-read-process-command-line-arguments)

Comment: This works when passed s argument. here the pasword is prompted and i want to pass it tried nit worked

Comment: Instead of `--ask-valut-pass` can you try [--vault-password-file](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.4/playbooks_vault.html#using-vault-in-playbooks) option? That way you just have pass the file path as one of subprocess.run argument.

Comment: @shiva that doesnt serve my requirement. i cant place my password file outside the python script. This ask for password file

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read the question properly.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using the cmdline `ansible-vault`, you can use the Python package - [ansible-vault](https://pypi.org/project/ansible-vault/) which will allow you to hardcode the password inside the script itself:

```
from ansible_vault import Vault

vault = Vault('password')
main_data = vault.load(open('main.yml').read())
linux_data = vault.load(open('linux.yaml').read())
```

As you are hardcoding the password inside the code, ensure you don't commit this code anywhere or send it to anyone, it's a serious security risk.

Comment: Even better- don't hardcode it into the code at all. Use a .env file to keep it secure, and use the security standards for that file (don't commit it to anywhere, etc.).