# How to pass a variable and extract them in the python script?

Tags: python

I am new to python and trying to pass the three variables in to the python script with the below command line..!

```
$ python C:\test.py --var_name1=cityname --ds_name2="state.sas7bdat" --path="C:\"
```

Below is the script that I use..

```
import re
import sys
args = {}
args['pythonFile'] =  sys.argv[0]
for arg in sys.argv[1:]:
  variable = re.search('\-\-(.*)\=',arg)
  variable = variable.group(1)
  value = re.search('\=(.*)',arg)
  value = value.group(1)
  args[variable] = value
print(args)
```

args prints

```
{'pythonFile': 'C:\test.py', 'var_name1'='cityname', 'ds_name2'='state.sas7bdat', 'path'='C:\'
```

Now, how would like to use `var_vame1`, `ds_name`, path variables in the python script?
for example..
I want to use..

```
filename=<PATH><DS_NAME>
```

how do I call these variables in the script?
Appreciate your help.

Comment: Try to use argpase modul, it makes this task lot easier

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read/process command line arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009860/how-to-read-process-command-line-arguments)