# Pass values from bash script to python script

Tags: python, bash, hpc

I'm working with an HPC where I write a bash script which executes my `python_script.py` job like so:

```
#!/bin/bash -l
#$ -l h_rt=0:00:10
#$ -l mem=1G
#$ -cwd

module load python3/3.8
python3 python_script.py
```

In my `python_script.py` I define the variables repeat, and directory like so:

```
repeat = 10
directory = r'User/somedir/'
```

I would like to be able to set these variables in my bash script, so that they overwrite these values within `python_script.py` and are used instead.

Comment: Pass the variables as arguments to your script. Or set them as environment variables in your bash script, then use `os.environ` in your Python script.

Comment: From the limited information in your question, I'd go with my first suggestion: pass the necessary variables as arguments to your script. Dive into the `argparse` module to make this easy (and safer) for your script.

Comment: Pendatic nitpick: your user name is missing an auxiliary verb.

Comment: Two ways: 1. Command line argument. 2. Environment variable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read/process command line arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009860/how-to-read-process-command-line-arguments)

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Yes, couldn't find this until now.

Comment: @9769953, max character limits alas, will consider the feedback.

Comment: I guess they should have taken the hobbits to Bree, that would have fit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easier way is to use in your python script :

```
import sys
repeat = sys.argv[1]
directory = sys.argv[2]
```

and in your bash script

```
repeat="10"
directory="User/somedir/"
python3 python_script.py $repeat $directory
```

Comment: For anyone else trying this: I found everything comes through as a string (even if using repeat=10 instead of repeat='10'), so just had to fix with repeat_int = int(repeat) in the python script and then use repeat_int from there on