# Is there any way to execute single part of my python script on command line Like output.py —u for user interface part And output.py —f for ftp part

Tags: command-line-arguments

Is there any way to execute single part of my python script on command line  Like output.py —u for user interface part  And output.py —f for ftp part

Comment: Have you checked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009860/how-to-read-process-command-line-arguments ?

Answer (score 0):

You can check for flags with this code: `'-d' in sys.arg`
Full code example:

```
import sys

if('-u' in sys.argv):
    # run user code part
    print('user part')

elif('-f' in sys.argv):
    #  ftp part
    print(' ftp part')
```