# How create variable from different input values on Python?

Tags: python, command-line-arguments

I am questioning of how I can create two variables containing two of the four input values. They are lat1 long1 lat2 long2 to calculate distance. Here is the code:

```
from geopy import distance


coords_1 = (lat1, long1)
coords_2 = (lat2, long2)

print (distance.distance(coords_1, coords_2).km)
```

Imagining that I would execute the code as

```
python3.9 distance.py -1 -28 -4 -32
```

where -1=lat1, -28=long1, -4=lat2, -32=long2.

Then, how can I include the input coordinates on the four variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Text you give into the program on the command line will be stored in `sys.argv`, along with the script's name. You can get, for example "-1", from `sys.argv[1]`. `sys.argv[0]` will be the script name.

```py
import sys
# ...

coords_1 = (int(sys.argv[1]), int(sys.argv[2]))
# adapt for coords_2

# ...
```

Comment: It works if all coordinates are integer. However, the coordinates are not integer and it shows the following error: coords_1 = (int(sys.argv[1]), int(sys.argv[2]))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '-28.33'

Comment: @gwsmelo Then use `float` instead of `int`.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the arguments from the 'sys' module. In your case:

```py
import sys

coords_1 = (sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2])
coords_2 = (sys.argv[3], sys.argv[4])
```

Or, for more readable code, you can do:

```py
import sys

lat1 = sys.argv[1]
long1 = sys.argv[2]
lat2 = sys.argv[3]
long2 = sys.argv[4]

coords_1 = (lat1, long1)
coords_2 = (lat2, long2)
```

These will be strings by default, so you will also probably want to convert them to ints with `int()`.

You can read more about commandline arguments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009860/how-can-i-read-and-process-parse-command-line-arguments).