# Python script argument conditional

Tags: python, command-line

Is anyone able to tell me how to write a conditional for an argument on a python script? I want it to print "Argument2 Entered" if it is run with a second command line arguments such as:

```
python script.py argument1 argument2
```

And print "No second argument" if it is run without command line arguments, like this:

```
python script.py argument1
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Sure it's possible. Have you tried anything yourself yet?

Comment: @Jimmy It's simple, python comes with batteries included, there is a module for that, argparse. Read the docs.

Comment: @dhunter I guess `argparse` is not required here.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary, yes it seems like a simple case but maybe the code will get bigger later, so pointing the mere existence of argparse may add some light, a "just in case" answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do this simple thing in Python. If you are interested to know more than I recommend to read [this](https://realpython.com/python-command-line-arguments) article. BTW I am giving you one solution below:

```
import click

'''
Prerequisite: # python -m pip install click
run: python main.py ttt yyy
'''

@click.command(context_settings=dict(ignore_unknown_options=True))
@click.argument("argument1")
@click.argument("argument2")
def main(argument1, argument2):
    print(f"argument1={argument1} and argument2={argument2}")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 3):

```
import sys

if len(sys.argv)==2: # first entry in sys.argv is script itself...
    print "No second argument"
elif len(sys.argv)==3:
    print "Second argument"
```

Answer (score 2):

There are many answers to this, depending on what exactly you want to do and how much flexibility you are likely to need.

The simplest solution is to examine the variable `sys.argv`, which is a list containing all of the command-line arguments. (It also contains the name of the script as the first element.) To do this, simply look at `len(sys.argv)` and change behaviour based on its value.

However, this is often not flexible enough for what people expect command-line programs to do. For example, if you want a flag (`-i`, `--no-defaults`, ...)  then it's not obvious how to write one with just `sys.argv`. Likewise for arguments (`--dest-dir="downloads"`). There are therefore many modules people have written to simplify this sort of argument parsing.

The built-in solution is `argparse`, which is powerful and pretty easy-to-use but not particularly concise.

A clever solution is `plac`, which inspects the signature of the `main` function to try to deduce what the command-line arguments should be.

Answer (score 1):

Following block should be self explanatory

```
$ ./first.py second third 4th 5th
5
$ cat first.py 
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys

print (len(sys.argv))
```

Comment: `len(sys.argv)-1` might be more appropriate since if a script run with no arguments will return 1

Answer (score 1):

This is related to many other posts depending upon where you are going with this, so I'll put four here:

[What's the best way to grab/parse command line arguments passed to a Python script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20063/whats-the-best-way-to-grab-parse-command-line-arguments-passed-to-a-python-scrip)
[Implementing a "[command] [action] [parameter]" style command-line interfaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/362426/implementing-a-command-action-parameter-style-command-line-interfaces)
[How can I process command line arguments in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/567879/how-can-i-process-command-line-arguments-in-python)
[How do I format positional argument help using Python's optparse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/642648/how-do-i-format-positional-argument-help-using-pythons-optparse)

But the direct answer to your question from the Python docs:

> **sys.argv** -
>       The list of command line arguments passed to a Python script. argv[0] is the script name (it is operating system dependent whether this is a full pathname or not). If the command was executed using the -c command line option to the interpreter, argv[0] is set to the string '-c'. If no script name was passed to the Python interpreter, argv[0] is the empty string.
>       To loop over the standard input, or the list of files given on the command line, see the fileinput module.